# Rails Neo4j Find all nodes related to some node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, neo4jrb

Say there are 2 models:

```
class A
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
    property :name, type: String
    has_many :in, :bs, type: :HAS_B
end

class B
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
    property :name, type: String
end
```

And following nodes and relations:

```
a1 <- b1
a2 <- b1
a3 <- b2
a1 <- b2
```

Now, I want all nodes of `label: A` that are in relation to a specific node of `label: B`.

How can I achieve that through neo4jrb?

In simple english, I want "All nodes labelled A which have a relation to node b1" (and this can be extended to multiple nodes, like all nodes of label A which have relation with nodes b1 and b2)

Comment: Why would anyone downvote without commenting. Suggest an improvement if there needs to be...if it is unclear or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
A.as(:a).B.where(name: [b1])
```

Here, for multiple `b's`, just send array of all required `b's`.

Note that, this query gives all `a's` which are connected to **any of** the `b's` in the array, which suited my requirement in this case. If you want something that gives all `a's` which are connected to **all** `b's`, this won't work. However, if anyone comes across such query, post it in comments and I will include it here in this post.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `:bs` association to `class B`.

```
class B
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
    property :name, type: String
    has_many :out, :bs, type: :HAS_B, model_class: :A
end
```

Then, after finding a particular node B, you can simply do `b.bs`. For example `B.where(id: some_id).bs`.

If you want to find all nodes of label A which have relation with nodes b1 OR b2, you could do

```
A.all.branch { bs.as(:b).where("b.uuid IN [$b1_id, $b2_id]") }.params(b1_id: b1_id, b2_id: b2_id)
```

If you want to find all nodes of label A which have relation with nodes b1 AND b2, you could do

```
A.all.branch { bs.where(id: b1_id) }.branch { bs.where(id: b2_id) }
```